# How to take part of a string in java?

Tags: java, string

I would like to know how to take parts of a long string to a string array.
For example turing:
`String str = "hi im john and my email is <john@hotmail.com> and my number is <0123456789>"` to `String[] strarray = {"john@hotmail.com", "0123456789"}`

Comment: Regex is your friend.

Comment: [You google it. That's a start.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: This is not related to Java. I suggest you remove java from the question. You want to find patterns in a string. Regular Expressions are a great tool for that , but you'd need to understand the theory behind them. Set theory, basic programming, finite state machines, regular languages, etc. Many tutorials claim that they are easy to learn. That's simply not true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would work :

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    String str = "hi im john and my email is <john@hotmail.com> and my number is <0123456789>";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<(.*?)>");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

O/P :

```
john@hotmail.com
0123456789
```